# Is it correct to use two different useState hook to store an array and a filtered array for passing to components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am currently porting my Pokemon project to React as I just learned the basics of React just a couple of weeks ago and want to see how well I can adapt it. Right now, the way I have my code architectured is to use two different useState hooks, one for the original array fetched from the PokeAPI and is only set once. This original array is also passed into my form object, which filters it according to a few form elements such as a Pokemon type or the Pokemon's name. And another useState hook is used to keep track of the filteredList which is what gets rendered to the website using the `Array.map()` function.

```
  const [pokemonList, setPokemonList] = useState([]);
  const [filteredList, setPokemonFilteredList] = useState([]);
```

Here's the `useEffect()` hook where we fetch and set the states

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getPokemon = async () => {
      const list = await fetchPokemon();
      setPokemonList(list);
      setPokemonFilteredList(list);
    };
```

And finally the `pokemonList` state variable and `setPokemonFilteredList` methods get passed into the `<PokemonSearchForm>`

```
<PokemonSearchForm pokemonList={pokemonList} setPokemonList={setPokemonFilteredList} />
```

So as my question title suggests, is the way I use two different `useState()` 'correct'? Maybe a different way is for the child component to access pokemonList variable? But I believe this may be an anti-pattern.

Comment: How do you apply filters? My recommendation would be to keep the _filters_ in state and just apply them where you need to on the original array. That way you don't have to maintain redundant/derived state.

Comment: The filtered are applied in my Form component using the information that is filled in from the form. 

Here's a small snippet of what that looks like: https://pastebin.com/C2LBvssJ
And here's an image of what the component itself looks like: https://imgur.com/a/rZeU8kF

Comment: Is this because you want to maintain filters through renders?  I guess I am confused on why you can't filter directly in the child component according to whatever view you're trying to show the user.

Comment: So it seems you should just maintain the filter information in state (e.g., type, searchType, search) and then filter during the render

Comment: This is a real easy use case, especially since your initial list should always remain the same.  Simply keep the filters stored in state and utilize them from there.

Comment: To be clear when you say 'in state' do you mean lifting up the state to the parent component and then do the filtering there, where I have direct access to the said array? Instead of trying to pass down the array to the form itself?

Comment: @Alex precisely. I'm writing an answer up, hopefully that will be clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better practice to *not* maintain duplicate or, in this case, *derived* state because you may run into *divergence*. For example, if your original pokemon data got updated, how would you make sure your filtered data got updated and then the filters re-applied? It gets hairy very fast.

The preferred alternative is to maintain the original data and filters in state and then compute the derived state (in this case, filter the list) during render.

```
function App() {
  const [pokemonList, setPokemonList] = useState([]);
  // Some default filter state
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    types: ["any"],
    search: ""
  });

  const filteredList = pokemonList.filter((pokemon) => {
    // Filter logic here
  });

  return <PokemonSearchForm setFilters={setFilters} />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor this in a few different ways:

1. Keep the filter state in your parent component, the child component will simply notify it when those change.
2. Ditch the `useState` for [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) which computes a value every time its dependencies change.

```js
function YourComponent() {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const list = await fetchPokemon();
      setPokemons(list);
    },
    []
  );

  // This will run each time `filters` or `pokemons` change.
  const filteredPokemons = useMemo(
    () => {
      return pokemons.filter((pokemon) => {
        // Perform any filtering logic you may have,
        // based on the filters set by the child component.

        if (filters.name) {
          return pokemon.name.includes(filters.name);
        }

        // etc...
      });
    },
    [filters, pokemons]
  );

  return (
    <PokemonSearchForm
      pokemons={filteredPokemons}
      onChange={setFilters}
    />
  );
}
```